# Website com R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown

Estou tentando criar um site para postar análises descritivas feitas em R, usando o tema Hugo. Porém, após criar uma postagem .Rmd onde leio um arquivo .csv e faço uma série de análises. Obtenho esse erro ao usar o comando serve_site() ou build_site()

```
Warning message:
In readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
  entrada inválida na conexão de entrada '2018-09-12-hello-world.Rmd'
Building sites â€¦ ERROR 2018/09/12 22:23:23 Failed to read data from 
__h__project\alex_turner.csv\alex_turner.csv: Data not supported for 
extension 'csv'
Total in 262 ms
Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
Building sites â€¦ ERROR 2018/09/12 22:23:24 Failed to read data from 
__h__project\alex_turner.csv\alex_turner.csv: Data not supported for 
extension 'csv'
Total in 103 ms
Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
O sistema nÆo pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\erick\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -d 
"../erickrdgs.github.io" -t hugo-tranquilpeak-theme' execution failed with 
error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read_utf8(f) :
  The file content/post/2018-09-12-hello-world.Rmd is not encoded in UTF-8. 
These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 33, 35, 37, 48, 50, 73, ...
2: running command '"C:\Users\erick\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -d 
"../erickrdgs.github.io" -t hugo-tranquilpeak-theme' had status 65535 
3: running command '"C:\Users\erick\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -d 
"../erickrdgs.github.io" -t hugo-tranquilpeak-theme' had status 65535 
4: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c 
"C:\Users\erick\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -d "../erickrdgs.github.io" - 
t hugo-tranquilpeak-theme' had status 1
```

O arquivo alex_turner.csv existe e está dentro de uma pasta 'data' na raiz do projeto. Alguém sabe o que pode causar esse erro e como posso resolvê-lo?

O repositório para o projeto em questão é https://github.com/erickrdgs/blogdown-source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aparentemente o teu código está correto. Rodei ele no meu PC (é um Mac, na verdade) e, a menos dos caracteres especiais (como em msicas, por exemplo), deu tudo certo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso me chamou a atenção sobre algum possível problema de character encoding. Note a seguinte linha na mensagem de erro que está no teu post:

```
The file content/post/2018-09-12-hello-world.Rmd is not encoded in UTF-8
```

Bingo. Taí o problema. O que fiz para solucioná-lo foi o seguinte:

1. Abri o arquivo `content/2018-09-12-hello-world.Rmd` no RStudio
2. Fui no menu `File > Save with Encoding...` e escolhi a opção UTF-8
3. Fechei o RStudio e abri de novo
4. Rodei o comando `blogdown::build_site(); blogdown::serve_site()` e o resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que agora os caracteres especiais aparecem todos (msicas virou músicas, como deveria ser).

Como tu usa Windows, minha solução é que todo arquivo que tu for criar no RStudio a partir de agora seja salvo através da opção `Save with Encoding...` com a opção UTF-8. Por algum motivo que desconheço, o Windows ainda não usa UTF-8 como encoding dos caracteres, o que gera muito problemas bizarros quando outros programas, como o Hugo, por exemplo, tentam acessar arquivos texto feitos em um editor do Windows.